# Why MUSIC algorithm fail when the antenna spacing is larger than half wavelength?

Tags: estimation, music, doa

I'm studying MUSIC algorithm for far-field DOA estimation. I found that when the antenna spacing $d$ is larger than half wavelength $(\frac{\lambda}{2})$, the algorithm fails and the spatial spectrum shows multiple peaks.

In 5G beyond and 6G wireless communications/localizations, mmWave or even higher THz band can be utilized, and thus the wavelengh might be smaller than a millimeter. However, it is quite challenging to manufacture an antenna array with such small element spacings in practice.

So my question is: **why MUSIC algorithm fail when the antenna spacing is larger than a half wavelength? Is there an intuitive explanation for this?**

Comment: This is strictly speaking a physics, not a signal processing question. Look at the antenna pattern of a linear array of parallel antennas, and you'll see these multiple lobes. Your problem simply doesn't have a unique solution anymore, and thus, MUSIC also can't solve the problem.

Comment: Easy enough: it's spatial aliasing. The sampling theorem applies in space the same way as it does in time. Since your not sampling densely enough you get mirror images in spatial frequency.

Comment: @Hilmar, you should add that as an answer.